# remove background line from form input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I remove the subtle grey line behind each of these inputs? I've looked and I can't find the css attribute that controls it and nothing obvious is showing up in the inspector. I'm using bootstrap and overriding the css as and when I need it.

[image]

Comment: Is that a box-shadow?

Comment: Did you already solve your question? Or do you still need help? If you need help, please provide us your html and css document.

Comment: Yes. adding `box-shadow: none;` to the css fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-shadow: none` to the CSS.  And mark the question answered.

Answer (score 0):

If it is from left side menu then, that is from `li` of `side-menu` ID selector.
Then add new stylesheet above tag `</head>`, and give border into `0px;` or `none`, as follows:

```
<style>
#side-menu li{
border:0px;
}
</style>
```